# I installed the Oracle JDK manually but cannot use it

Tags: installation, java, paths

I have downloaded `jdk1.6.0_32.bin` (Sun JDK) from Oracle file, and I installed it in `/usr/lib/jvm`. Now when I try to compile a Java source file using `javac` it says:

```
 The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.4-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

It means that it is not getting the path of my installed java. Do I need to set a path? How can I make it to work?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should move the Sun JDK from `/usr/lib/jvm` to `/usr/local/lib/jvm`. Let the package manager manage all files in `/usr`, except under `/usr/local`, which is for files not managed by the package manager.

`java` and other executables need to be in your path. This happens automatically when you install a Java environment from Ubuntu, but Ubuntu does not ship the Oracle JRE (for legal reasons). So you need to one of two things:

- Add the `/usr/local/lib/jvm/bin` directory to your path.
- Create symbolic links from `/usr/local/lib/jvm/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`, by typing the following commands in a terminal:

  ```
  cd /usr/local/bin
  ln -s ../lib/jvm/bin/* .
  ```

I recommend the second method, that's what `/usr/local/bin` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the following article: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/java-update-script-for-ubuntu-version.html
It has reference to the Java Update Script; works like a charm if you want to download and install the JDK manually. I have used this one personally and it does save on a lot of effort and potential problems.

OR,

You can add the PPA referenced in this article: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html